# How can I get checkboxes not in datagrid selected based on database value Y and N?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes, I want them to be selected depending on a value from sql server database.  The database has 2 columns Name and Relocate.  If the Relocate value is Y, I want the checkbox to be selected.

Table:

```
Name | Relocate |
-----------------
John | Y        | 
Jane | N        | 
Mike | Y        |
```

I know I need to have the 3 checkboxes associated to John, Jane and Mike but i'm not exactly sure how to go about this.  Here's what I have tried but all the checkboxes are selected.  2 of the checkboxes should be selected (John and Mike) but 1 checkbox should not (Jane).

ASP.NET

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRelocate" runat="server" />
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRelocate0" runat="server" />
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRelocate1" runat="server" />
```

Cobebehind C#

```
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Relocate FROM Employees", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    chkRelocate.Checked = dr["Relocate"].ToString() == "Y";
                    chkRelocate0.Checked = dr["Relocate"].ToString() == "Y";
                    chkRelocate1.Checked = dr["Relocate"].ToString() == "Y";
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could show the code for the DataGrid rather than just the CheckBoxes. However, I would think it would be as easy as `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRelocate" runat="server" Checked="` whatever you want the Checked property to be...

Comment: How do you populate data to DataGrid?

Comment: I'm not using a datagrid.  All the solutions I could find by searching online showed datagrids, so I'm just specifying that I am not using a datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem in your code is that you are setting all 3 chackboxes the value at the same time. So at first iteration it sets all to "Checked", at 2nd all to "unchecked" and at 3rd all to "checked".
Also - if your "con" is inside the "using" then why do you you specify in extra con.Open() and con.Close()?

In the case of having guaranteed only 3 items then I would say (though this would be a bad approach):

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBoxValues = new bool[3]();
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Relocate FROM Employees", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                var i = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    checkBoxValues[i] = dr["Relocate"].ToString() == "Y";
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        chkRelocate.Checked = checkBoxValues[0];
        chkRelocate0.Checked = checkBoxValues[1];
        chkRelocate1.Checked = checkBoxValues[2];
    }
}
```

a better approach would be to put the checkboxes into a list it self - so you could iterate and set the variable values withing the while loop. So you might want to use CheckBoxList (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This method worked.  To answer your question as to why I specify an extra con.open...it's because I get the following error if I don't: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: yeap you're right - but you don't have to "Close" it - as the using statement closes it as it moves out from it. (I edited my answer accordingly)

Comment: Okay, so what if the rows will continue to grow and won't be just those 3?

Comment: @Dr.Prog Then you should use the checkBoxList (in fact you should research into using it anyways). As my answer was by counting on "I know I need to have the 3 checkboxes associated to John, Jane and Mike". Also - if it is your personal project for learning - you might want to use MVC standard instead of Web Forms (It would improve both quality and development speed).

Comment: Then in Web you could use something like: 
`@foreach(var item in Model.Answers
{
@Html.Label(@item.Name):&nbsp;@Html.CheckBox@item.Answer)
}`